# What relation must hold between the sets A and B in order for the given condition to be true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know there is no B in this equation but this is one of the problems I was given and I am having trouble understanding it:

$$A' \cap U = \varnothing$$

Where $A'=$ complement $A$ and $U$ is the universal set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A'=U\setminus A $ and since $A'\cap U =\emptyset$, it follows that $U=A$.

*Proof*:$\quad$
Suppose $x\in U$. If $x\not\in A$, then $x\in U\setminus A$ and thus $x\in (U\setminus A) \cap U$ which is a contradiction. So, $x\in A$ and hence $U\subseteq A$. Also, $A\subseteq U$, and so $A=U$.

So, we have the relation $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Would the proof be that any set is a subset of the universal set and A = U?

Comment: @lampwins I've added a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no $B$ in the proposition "$A' \cap U=\emptyset$", $B$ can be any subset of $U$, and it won't affect its truth.

If $a \in A'$, then $a \in U$ which implies $a \in A' \cap U$.  Hence $A' \cap U=\emptyset$ implies that $A'=\emptyset$.  Thus, $A=(A')'=\emptyset'=U$.